# Bubble sort program is not working properly.

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I have to create a bubble sort program in C# that sorts random integers stored in array. I have to do these for arrays with lengths 100, 1,000, 10,000 ect. I have some code that runs and compiles correctly, but does not perform right. The code is below:

```
using System;

namespace SortingProject
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] list = {100};

            Random rand = new Random();


            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++) {

                list[i] = rand.Next(1,100);
            }



            BubbleSorting(list);


        }

        public static void BubbleSorting(int [] array) {

            int first = 0;

            for (int sorted = 0; sorted < array.Length; sorted++)
            {
                for (int sort = 0; sort < array.Length - 1; sort++)
                {
                    if (array[sort] > array[sort + 1])
                    {
                        first = array[sort + 1];
                        array[sort + 1] = array[sort];
                        array[sort] = first;
                    }
                }

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                Console.Write(array[i] + " ");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }




    }
    }
```

When I run the program, the output is only one randomly generated integer and I was wondering why this was happening? I know something in my code is not working properly but am I properly executing a bubble sort? I am not seeing what is wrong the code.

Comment: Your array is only one element long.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change this:

```
 int[] list = {100};
```

for this:

```
 int[] list = new int[100];
```